# could not find implicit value for parameter functor: cats.Functor[Some]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am trying to follow a simple example from the scala with cats ebook. here is my code

```
import cats.Semigroupal
import cats.instances.option._
import cats.syntax.apply._
import cats.implicits._
case class Name(fName: String, lName: String)
(Some("foo"), Some("bar")).mapN(Name.apply)
```

I get the error

```
cmd4.sc:1: could not find implicit value for parameter functor: cats.Functor[Some]
val res4 = (Some("foo"), Some("bar")).mapN(Name.apply)
```

I also tried importing

```
cats.functor._
cats.syntax.functor._
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Functor is invariant in its type argument, so you need to make the Scala compiler treat the type of the tuple as `(Option[String], Option[String])` instead of `(Some[String], Some[String])`. You can do this using

```
("foo".some, "bar".some).mapN(Name.apply)
```