# folding of list of options is compile error

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

why the second folding compile error ?

I think the first folding and the second one are completely same.
But the second one arise compile error.

```scala
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.syntax.all._

val somes : List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(2))
Foldable[List].fold(somes)
Foldable[List].fold(List(Some(1), Some(2)))
```

compile error message is

```
No given instance of type cats.kernel.Monoid[Some[Int]] was found for parameter A of method fold in trait Foldable
```

I expect the code is compiled.

Comment: In first case you are folding a list of `Option[Int]`, and in the second case it is inferred as `List[Some[Int]]`, that fails because `Some` isn't a `Monoid`. Try `fold(List[Option[Int]](Some(1), Some(2))`

Comment: You can also use cats smart constructors for Options: `fold(1.some :: 2.some :: Nil)` (in addition to @Dima 's comment)

Comment: @Dima  thank you. giving the type annotation makes it compiled.

Answer (score -2):

[Doc tells](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/foldable.html) that you need to import implicits as well

```
import cats.implicits._
```

[here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50186688/10078818) regarding Some and Option

Comment: OP already imported `cats.syntax.all._`. So there's no need to import `cats.implicits._` (syntaxes are already imported and instances do not need to be imported in recent Cats because the instances are in implicit scope).

Comment: Moreover, **additional** import `cats.implicits._` is just wrong. With `import cats.syntax.all._` `Foldable[List].fold(1.some :: 2.some :: Nil)` compiles. So it does with `import cats.implicits._`. But it doesn't compile with `import cats.syntax.all._; import cats.implicits._`.

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Esp. linking to Stack Overflow answers isn't useful. It probably means that the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @GertArnold Well, actually linking **is** useful. Just links should be comments, not answers. Or answers should be not only links.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Sure, but marking as duplicate is also linking of sorts.